# XML Parsing fails at empty line after body

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an xml file and .parse() returns false and I don't know why. It fails at the next line after I close the body. Anyone has a clue why this is happening? My code is below and I've attached some screenshots as well:

```
func parseXMLFileWithName(_ name : NSString) {
    let path = String(Bundle.main.path(forResource: name as String, ofType: "xml")!)
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
    let parser = XMLParser(data: data as Data)
    parser.delegate = self
    if !parser.parse() {
        let error = parser.parserError
        let line = parser.lineNumber
        let col = parser.columnNumber
        print("XML parsing failed at \(line):\(col): \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
    }
}

private func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

    if elementName == "word" {

        let newWord = NSMutableDictionary()
        var correctWord = true
        var currentType = ""

        if let type = attributeDict["type"] as? String {
            newWord["type"] = type
            currentType = type
        } else {
            correctWord = false
        }

        if let value = attributeDict["value"] as? String {
            newWord["value"] = value
        } else {
            correctWord = false
        }

        if let trans = attributeDict["trans"] as? String {
            newWord["trans"] = trans
        } else {
            correctWord = false
        }

        //if everything was ok, tag "word" has all 3 attributes than i add the new dictionary to the array of nsdictionary
        if correctWord == true {
            let wordDict = NSDictionary(dictionary: newWord)
            allElements.append(wordDict)
            if currentType == "word" {
                words.append(wordDict)
            }

            if currentType == "phrase" {
                phrases.append(wordDict)
            }

            if currentType == "dict" {
                dicts.append(wordDict)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I'm not getting the error anymore. I was calling parser.parse() too many times. Problem is it won't append my dicts dictionary.
[image: smaller version of the xml file i'm using]

Comment: We need a reproduceable issue here so we need same XML that breaks. Edit the file down so that we can reproduce with a smaller file

Comment: Why are you calling `parser.parse()` three times? That's bad. Call it once.